# Wordpress Categories and Tags not linking

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am not sure why this issue has risen up, never had this problem in any of my other blogs that I have done. But perhaps someone is able to shed some light on this.

I have a list of posts.
TITLE | CATEGORIES | DATE

The title links correctly, But the CATEGORIES do not. My Code for displaying the category is:

```
<li class="category"><?php the_category(', ') ?></li>
```

When I click the category link it displays **404 not found** but there is a URL issue that comes in:
http://domain.com/categoryName
*SHOULD BE*
http://domain.com/**category**/categoryName

I do have the exact same issue with the TAGS but I don't know what to reference for the TAG feature.

I used the Default Widget for "most popular tags" and it just doesn't link properly no matter what... and it too has the url of:

http://domain.com/tagName

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about this post, it was an issue with the previous theme-author.
He removed the the code for the categories.

Answer (score 0):

The function `the_category()` only returns the category names, where are you generating the href?. Wherever you're specifying the url in your code, you should just be able to add `/category/`. I'd need to see more code to be more helpful.

Also, the_category() will return all the categories, so if you have more than one category, it might screw up your url more. Again, would need to see more code.